# C++ Need help iterating through cards, locating pairs and flush's

Tags: c++

The program below is suppose to be looking for "Pair's" and "Flush's". It iterates through 10 Trials consisting of 10,000 hands, each hand consisting of 5 cards. The result should (of course it doesn't right now) consist of 10 rows reflecting unique results for each trial. I am stuck...thanks in advance.

```
#include "card.h"
#include "deck.h"
#include "game1.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


int main() {

int pair = 0;
int flush = 0;
int h;  //Hands
int c;  //Cards
int t;  //Trials

const int MAXTRIALS = 10;
const int MAXHANDS = 10000;
const int MAXCARDS = 5;
const int MAXSHUFFLE = 100;

Deck myDeck;
Card myCards[MAXCARDS];
myDeck.shuffle(MAXSHUFFLE);                         //How often would you shuffle?

srand((unsigned)time(NULL));                        //Randon initilizer

for (t = 0 ; t < MAXTRIALS; ++t)                    //Outermost loop for the Trials
{   

    for (h = 0; h < MAXHANDS; ++h)                  //InnerLoop for Hands
    {

        myCards[0] = myDeck.getCard();
        for (c = 1; c < MAXCARDS; ++c)              //InnerMost Loop for Cards
        {
            myCards[c] = myDeck.getCard();
            if (myCards[c].getValue() == myCards[0].getValue()) 
            {
                pair++;                 
            }

            if (myCards[c].getSuit() == myCards[0].getSuit())
            {
                flush++;                        
            }

            myDeck.addCard(myCards[c]);
            c++;

        }
        myDeck.shuffle(MAXSHUFFLE); 
        h++;
    }

    cout << "pairs: " << pair << "\tflushes: " << flush << endl;

}
cin.get();
}
```

[image]

Comment: I feel like this would be much easier to solve if several functions were utilized rather than triply-nested `for` loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a lot of guessing what exactly should happen...

1) Is it made sure, that `myDeck.getCard()` does not draw the same card twice? Or does it not matter for your task?

2) What is `myDeck.addCard(myCards[c])` exactly doing?

3) Why do you increment the loop counter a second time? `c++`

If this is made sure, you are only comparing against the first card. If you want to compare a complete hand, your code should look something like this:

```
// first draw the complete hand
for(int card = 0; card < MAX_CARDS; ++card)
{
    myCards[card] = myDeck.getCard();
}
// now that we have the full hand, compare each card against each other card
for(int start = 0; start < MAXCARDS-1; ++start)
{
    for(int compare = start+1; compare < MAXCARDS; ++compare)
    {
        if (myCards[start].getValue() == myCards[compare].getValue())
        {
            pair++
        }
        // do similar for flushs
    }
}
```

I didn't test this code, but this should give you a start.

This would count every pair, even if there are two pairs in one hand. It would need additional code to break out of the loops, if a pair was found.

btw: looks like homework to me...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, "the result should ... consist of 10 rows reflecting unique results for each trial", the problem is simply that you don't reset the `pair` and `flush` counter variables between each trial.  Something like the following where the 'trial' `for` loop starts should do the trick:

```
for (t = 0 ; t < MAXTRIALS; ++t) 
{
    pair = 0;
    flush = 0;

    // the remainder as is...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `c++` and `h++` are a little bit suspicious (did you really mean to only touch every other item)? But without more information as to what you are observing, it would be hard to give a definitive answer.

Also, some minor stylistic recommendations regarding your code:

1. I recommend putting off the declaration of "h", "c", and "t" to the first point at which they are needed, so I would declare them in the for-loop (e.g. "for (int h = 0; h < ... ; h++)").
2. It is more idiomatic to use `static_cast` in C++ code (i.e. `srand(static_cast(time(NULL)))`), than it is to use a C-style cast, however both forms are correct.